# create select in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a little confused with joomla 2.5

I have a component (product) with name, description and category.
I want to do a select to find a product selecting the category...

In the view of the front-end I show all the product, and I put a select here

```
<?php echo JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $options,'myfilter', 'class="inputbox"','value','text'); ?>
<?php if($this->items) : ?>
    <div class="items">
        <ul class="items_list">
            <?php foreach ($this->items as $item) :?>                
        <li><?php echo $item->nombre; ?></li>
                <li><?php echo $item->descripcion; ?></li>
                <li><?php echo $item->nivel; ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

but I don´t know how to call the controller and model if I select one item of select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to:

- Wrap your `<select>` with a `<form>` tag
- replace first line of your code with:

> < ?php echo JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $options, 'myfilter', 'class="inputbox" onchange="this.form.submit()"' ,'value', 'text'); ?>

- Write your Controller and Model. A good tutorial can be found at:

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Introduction

- set appropriate  parameters in order to point joomla to the right controller. eg:

> ```
> <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_helloworld" />
> <input type="hidden" name="task" value="updhelloworld.submit" />
> ```